# How to create a new AWS instance using AWS Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to create a new AWS EC2 instance using the AWS Java SDK but getting **"Value () for parameter groupId is invalid. The value cannot be empty"**.  Here is my code:

```
AWSCredentials credentials = null;
try {
    credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new AmazonClientException(
        "Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " +
        "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct " +
        "location (~/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.",
        e);
}

ec2 = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.standard()
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
    .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2)
    .build();
```

}

```
RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest();
String ami_id = "ami-efd0428f";     //ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-20170414
Collection<String> securityGroups = new ArrayList<>();
securityGroups.add("launch-wizard-1");
securityGroups.add("sg-9405c2f3");
runInstancesRequest.withImageId(ami_id) 
    .withInstanceType("t2.medium")
    .withMinCount(1)
    .withMaxCount(1)
    .withKeyName("MyKeyName")
    .withSecurityGroups(securityGroups);

RunInstancesResult run_response = ec2.runInstances(runInstancesRequest);  // fails here!

String instance_id = run_response.getReservation().getReservationId();

Tag tag = new Tag()
    .withKey("Name")
    .withValue(tfCompanyName.getText());
Collection<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();
tags.add(tag);

CreateTagsRequest tag_request = new CreateTagsRequest();
tag_request.setTags(tags);

CreateTagsResult tag_response = ec2.createTags(tag_request);

String s = String.format("Successfully started EC2 instance %s based on AMI %s",instance_id, ami_id);
System.out.println(s);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add a VPC details also .

PrivateIpAddresses ,Monitoring are among other required fields.

I would recommend you to try creating EC2 Instance manually using AWS Console and see what are the required parameters it is asking?

Comment: The VPC thing is probably the issue as I do have one of those (whatever it is).  How do I include it?  I don't see any .withVPC options.

Comment: I created one with the AWS Console.  The only thing required was an AMI, Type, and KeyPair